# I have changed Visual Studio's "go to definition" shortcut, but it doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio

I used Ctags before in Linux. Its shortcuts for 'go to definition' and 'go back' are 'Ctrl+]' and 'Ctrl+t'.

Now I try to bind these shortcuts to Visual Studio, whose default keys are 'F12' and 'Ctrl+-' separately.

I changed 'go back' with 'Ctrl+t' successfully. But 'go to definition' can't be changed with 'Ctrl+]'. I add new key-binding to it and remove previous key-binding. The right-click menu shows the new key-binding but it doesn't work.
Is there something wrong with my steps?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community version. My os is Windows 10 professional edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other commands also using that keybinding, in a more specific context.  For example, on my machine, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is bound to the Edit.GotoBrace command in the Text Editor.  If your keybinding is in a less-specific context (like Global), then the Text Editor command would take precedent when the editor is active.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I have removed Edit.GotoBrace with 'Ctrl+]' and it worked! Thank you again!